# Possibility of subtraction.

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

In Apostol's Calculus Volume I book, there is a theorem, named **Possibility of Subtraction**, which states:

Given $a$ and $b$, there is exactly one $x$ such that $a + x = b$. This $x$ is denoted by $b - a$. In particular, $0 - a$ is written simply $-a$ and is called the negative of $a$.

Its proof is:
Given $a$ and $b$, choosy $y$ so that $a + y = 0$ and let $x = y + b$.
Then, $a + x = a + (y + b) = (a + y) + b = 0 + b = b$.
Therefore there is at least one $x$ such that $a + x = b$.
But by (another theorem) there is at most one such $x$.
Hence, there is exactly one.

QED

Now my question is that the only axioms that we are supposed to use to prove this theorem are:

- Commutative laws
- Associative laws
- Distributive law
- Existence of identity elements
- Existence of negatives
- Existence of reciprocals

The thing is that the axiom that says that: if $a \in R$ and $b \in R$, then $a + b \in R$ has not yet been stated.
Given this, I don't understand how we can prove the existence of that $x$ without having this order axiom.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have Apostol to hand right now. Are you sure that there isn't an earlier assumption or proof that $R$ is closed under addtion?

Comment: But $a\in R\ and\ b\in R$ are not part of the proof

Comment: @EthanBolker, you are right, and I misread the book. Sorry. 
The book indeed says what you said, but not explicitly (I mean, it is not an axiom [shouldn't it be?]).
And the order axiom that I was mentioning, was actually for $R^+$ and not simply $R$.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe I forgot to mention that at the beginning of all theorems it is said that a, b, c and d are assumed to be arbitrary real numbers.

Comment: What should I do with this question?